# Should questions with tag [contacts] be retagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Recently I went through the list of questions tagged with [contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts). The tag was meant to indicate an action involving a list of contacts on your mobile phone. However, from what I can deduct [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact) was merged with [contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) some time ago. It might seem like it was a good idea, but a lot of people started using this ambiguous tag for things like contact forms on the web.

IMHO it doesn't deserve burninantion, because it answers at least 3 out of 4 questions, despite the cool puns e.g. *"We made first [contact]!"* or *"I dropped my [contacts]."*

I would like to propose that we retag the questions with less ambiguous tags wherever possible and add information about it in the tag excerpt.

- [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)[android-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contacts)
- [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)[ios-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-contacts)
- [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone)[ios-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-contacts)
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)[contact-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form)
- [contact-form-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form-7)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => [contact-form-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form-7)[contact-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form) or just leave [contact-form-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form-7) on its own
- [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => ??? [the excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CGPO.png) for [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact) suggest that maybe this was the original use for that tag
- [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => either [contact-form-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form-7) or [contact-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form)
- [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api)
- [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms)[contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts) => [contact-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341856/vtiger-6-4-google-sync-no-access-control) => [google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api)
- and all other variations of the above within reason

There are of course some oddballs for example:
[How can I calculate the area in which two cuboids faces make contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55657347/1839439)
[How can I make an  only active on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13409089/1839439)
[Authorization request (add to roster) using strophe.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505949/1839439)
[Database design - Similar Contact Information for multiple entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3636061/1839439)

I understand that my idea might not be the best, so I am asking for opinions and guidance. In some situations this tag makes the question more difficult to locate e.g. [How to load call logs faster like other apps and display like attached image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46219231/1839439). Maybe a burnination would be a better idea? But, what would happen to questions which are about contacts, but fall into neither of the categories listed above e.g. [How to access contacts list in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4107139/1839439)?

There is also a tag [addressbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addressbook), which honestly I do not know how it differs from [contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts).

Answer (score 1):

[google-contacts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) has [google-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts) as a synonym. Should they stay this way?

Nowadays, Google Contacts API is deprecated and retired, so this might not be very convenient.

I don't think appropriate to look at Google Contacts just as an app.

1. It's a brand encompassing several things, one of which is a cross-platform app. The details for end-users are on https://support.google.com/contacts.
2. People API can handle authenticated user contacts and more programmatically. For details, see https://developers.google.com/people.
3. Some information in Google Contacts might require other APIs like the Google Workspace Admin SDK.
4. Data from Google Contacts interacts with many other Google apps, Android and possibly more things.

Related

- [What should we do with [google-contacts-api] (deprecated and retired)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426717/1595451)